# How to make fluent hibernate took updated values from database?

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am taking data from database by using Fluent NHibernate.

```
public class OfferMap : ClassMap<tOffer>
{
    public OfferMap()
    {
        Table("tOffer");

        Id(m => m.Id, "OfferId");

        Map(m => m.UserId);
        Map(m => m.AtPremisesId, "Location");
        Map(m => m.RegNo);
        Map(m => m.ReceiveDate);
        Map(m => m.HasTypeApproval, "TypeApproval");
        Map(m => m.Email, "OperatorEMail");
        Map(m => m.Fax, "OperatorFax");
        Map(m => m.Phone, "OperatorTelephone");
    }
}
```

I have a tool which receives updates from database.

The issue is that when tool is started, it will receive only first update.

For example: I changed `ReceiveDate` to *6 May* on web page. Tool and hibernate took it normally. Again, I changes `ReceiveDate` to *8 May* on web page. Fluent NHibernate received *6 May*.

As I understand Hibernate receive first value, and don't want to take changes which are done not by him.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless NHibernate can know about the change *(the change which went through NHibernate session)*, the only way is to use explicit call **`.Refresh(myObject)`**:

#### [9.2. Loading an object](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-loading)

> ... It is possible to re-load an object and all its collections at any time, using the **`Refresh()`** method. This is useful when database triggers are used to initialize some of the properties of the object...

This way we could get the instance with all up to date settings:

```
session.Refresh(myObject);
```

Comment: Hm... is there a way to simple disable hibernate cashe?

Comment: I mean. is there are option to disable cache in Fluently.Configure()  ?

Comment: This is not about the cache. Not about second level, nor first. Simply, NHibernate cannot load always. It does once, then expects that it has up to date data. If we believe it is not true... we have to use explicit `.Refresh()` call. Does it help?

Comment: Well,  I understand the Idea. Will try to make it work (actually, the problem is that I don't call or create nhibernate directly, I have a wrap for it and... this make Refresh call a lot harder.).

Comment: Then also, please, check Merge() in the doc.. but mostly, simply rethink the approach. Maybe, if your application will start to call for a fresh data (Find, GetById) ... via your standard API... in regular times.. all will be solved. Refresh is there for objects, which are still in session, but we do not think, that they are up to date. Merge is for objecgts which are not in session. But in your case... regular reload could work much more better....

Comment: If you are using GetById.. then the issue could be only with second level cache. Start with checking the settings: `    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>`

Comment: Where can I exactly find those properties? (Sorry for may be stupid question).

Comment: Your questions are NOT stupid. It is great to see that you try to learn it. Here is link to doc http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#caches and http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-querycache

Comment: As I understand, property name is for... files. So, for fluent it will be something similar to Fluently.Configure().Cache(c => c.Not.UseSecondLevelCache()); ?

Comment: Yes! this is the way with fluent

Comment: It seems the problem could in fact be the first-level cache if Olegs doesn't drops or resets the Session every now and then. Not clear from the question.